# Cannot link to a webpart on SPO page with certain parameters

Tags: reactjs, hyperlink, modal-dialog, sharepoint-online, spfx

I have created a hyperlink which opens up a modal that shows a specific item from a SharePoint Online list.
Here's what I've got so far (with help from AmosWu!):

```
private  _filterListOnEmail = () => { //this runs on componentdidmount
    
    var urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);

    var urlParamstoString = urlParams.toString();
    
    var justUrl = window.location.href;

    var trimHref = justUrl.split('&')[0];

    var trimHref2 = trimHref.substring(trimHref.indexOf("=") + 1);
    
    var txtUrlParams = urlParams.toString();

    var trimtxtUrlParams = txtUrlParams.substring(3);
    
    this.setState({
      urlParams: trimHref2
    },  () => {
 
      if(urlParamstoString){
        this.setState({
          showWelcomeModal: true,
          ByEmail: 'Yes',
      
      });
    }
```

The URL I have constructed:

```
<a href={`https://mytenant.sharepoint.com/sites/MySite?ID=${this.props.id}`}>Here</a>
```

This works if the URL is https://mytenant.sharepoint.com/sites/MySite?ID=1 and it shows my modal and it gets the correct ID and shows the correct list item. But if it's ID=2 or any other number, the page shows **No item exists at
https://mytenant.sharepoint.com/sites/MySite/SitePages/Home.aspx?ID=2**
I don't understand why it's putting the extra SitePages/Home.aspx on the end....I guess this is causing the No item exists error.
The webpart is on the home page of the SP site.
**It works with any ID number in workbench but not when deployed.**
Really need help with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My test result:
[image]
[image]
I show the editform in the modal, it works well.

The code is the code I shared with you in Q&A. If you need the complete project code, please let me know and I will share it on Github.

Comment: Hi @Amos_MSFT - I am constructing the hyperlink like so: <a href={`https://mytenant.sharepoint.com/sites/myhomepage?ID=${this.props.id}`} 
And I've used a split and substring to remove everything to the left and right of the ID=1 (for e.g.). But this causes problems because I think it's removing the authentication token. Does a RegExp work in this case?

Comment: I've updated my question which is more focused on the problem.

Comment: You need to make sure that the URL of the page you want to display in the dialog is correct. The format you use is easy for SharePoint to think that it is the page of a certain item, and then do not enter the page you originally wanted to enter. The server searches for the page of that item so that the code will not trigger.

Comment: I understand, could you give me a code example on gitHub?

Comment: https://github.com/Amos-MSFT/SharePoint-FrameWork-Demos/tree/master/PnpControlSPFX
I manually modified the url to do the test, the code I tested before was commented by me.